# Creating a Lexer

Tags: python, lexer

Hey guys i am trying to understand some concepts regarding lexers. I understand that lexers are used in compilers to separate individual characters in a string into the form known as tokens. But the thing that confuses me is the matching part. I do not understand the logic of why we need to match the characters to the corresponding position.

```
import sys
import re

def lex(characters, token_exprs):
    pos = 0
    tokens = []
    while pos < len(characters):
        match = None
        for token_expr in token_exprs:
            pattern, tag = token_expr
            regex = re.compile(pattern)
            match = regex.match(characters, pos)
            if match:
                text = match.group(0)
                if tag:
                    token = (text, tag)
                    tokens.append(token)
                break
        if not match:
            sys.stderr.write('Illegal character: %s\n' % characters[pos])
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            pos = match.end(0)
    return tokens
```

This is the code that i do not completely understand. After the for loop, i do not quite grasp what the code is trying to do.Why do we have to match the characters to the position?

Comment: Exactly which bit of code do you think is "matching the characters to the position"?

Comment: match = regex.match(characters,pos)

Comment: @DanielRoseman probably the line that says `match`, `characters`, and `pos`

Comment: After the for loop, it checks to see if a match has been made at position `pos` or not.  If not, it throws an error message and exits.  If it does match, it skips to the end of the token it found to continue, checking if the next bunch of characters matches a token pattern.

Comment: is the purpose of the lexer to find characters that aren't comprehandable by the computer like: Ü or ä?

Comment: So you copied this code from  https://github.com/Chownie/Python-Logo/blob/master/lexer.py (which appears down right now). Do you have any idea what it is supposed to do? Without the value of `token_exprs` it is impossible to guess its intent.

Comment: Github is back up and the place you took that from is horribly incomplete and hasn't changed in a year. Might I suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis instead of broken code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pretty traditional lexer can work something like this:

1. Get a character from somewhere, be it a file or a buffer
2. Check what the current character is:

   - Is it a whitespace? Skip all whitespace
   - Is it a comment introduction character? Get and skip the comment
   - Is it a digit? Then try to get a number
   - Is it a `"`? Then try to get a string
   - Is it a character? Then try to get an identifier

     - Is the identifier a keyword/reserved word?
   - Otherwise, is it a valid operator sequence?
3. Return the token type

Instead of checking single characters at a time, you can of course use regular expressions.

---

The best way to learn how a hand-written lexer works, is (IMO) to find simple existing lexers and try to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't match "characters to the position". The "pos" parameters is given to seek the pattern only in the part of the "characters" string - starting from index=pos to end. So the code tries to match given tokens in the given order to the given string. After a token is found in the string, the next tokens are being matched only to the remaining part of the string.
It's not a lexer strictly speaking, as it does a bit more than a lexer should do (refer to Joachim Pileborg's answer or to Lexer's [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)).

Comment: Where does it do more than a lexer "should" do?

Comment: For example it verifies that tokens are in correct order.